# dot in url returns 404 error (.htaccess)

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have some URL that includes dots (.) in them as a name.
Whenever I'm trying to access them, I get 404 error.

This is my page rewrite condition:

```
RewriteRule ^location/([0-9]+)-([^./*]+)?$ ?page=viewLocation&id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

What's wrong here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thats because your regex pattern does not match dot in url

Remove the dot from [^./*]
Try :

```
RewriteRule ^location/([0-9]+)-([^/*]+)?$ ?page=viewLocation&id=$1&name=$2 [L]
```

[^./*] matches  any charecters in uri excluding "." "/" and * .